# Navbar button not appearing bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The navbar button is just not appearing i don't know whats wrong.
I am sure that the code is correct i even have jquery file.

This is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
      <header>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </nav>
      </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have 2 html tags before the head it's can cause a problem?

Comment: You are not adding anything to the navbar. The button you added is one button to show the menu on smaller devices. Just resize your screen down and the hamburguer icon will show in the right. In the official Bootstrap website you have plenty of examples: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: I figured it out thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `navbar-expand-md` class in your nav element because of that your toggle is only visible in resolution smaller than 768px and for higher resolution you can use `navbar-expand-lg` or `navbar-expand-xl` classes. If you want to keep it visible in all screen just remove the class `navbar-expand`

```
  <body>
  <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Thanks , i figured it out later!

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't make any sense. Can you adjust this for yourself and try it ? The navbar toggler also needs to have a specific width value to appear.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">***Your İmg Here***</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```